# php regex non-match group

Tags: php, regex

i have string

```
<font><font>sdasdsa</font></font>
```

how to match string with regex

```
<font>sdasdsa</font>
```

i tried this pattern but it cannot match

```
<font>[^(<font>)]*?</font>
```

Comment: If you know, there's no tags inside `<font>`...`</font>` the simplest way possibly is just to match [negated](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `<` between. Pattern like `~<font>[^<]*</font>~` ([see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nS1fH5/1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<font>(?:(?!<font>).)*?<\/font>
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/23)